# WordPress or Joomla for company's intranet?

Tags: wordpress, cms

My boss asked me to create a new intranet for the company. I like WordPress (also for its simplicity) but I think Joomla is more a CMS "intranet" oriented. 
Am I wrong?

The needs are:

1. Publish company information
2. Publish link to services (ticketing system, address book)
3. Publish documentation

Is WordPress suitable for company intranet?

Comment: Please see the [FAQ] for further clarification on what kind of questions are a good fit here. This question specifically falls in to the category discussed in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend Joomla or even Drupal. From my experience Joomla is easier to configure but Drupal is more powerful but harder to learn. They both have tons of free plugins / addons that can do what you need. Both also have tons of free templates / themes to make your site look the way you want.

Wordpress would be great if you just want to post status updates and information but I'm not certain it would fare well with ticketing and other types of functions.

Comment: @stighy and you could always try the http://drupal.stackexchange.com if you go with Drupal :)

Answer (score 2):

Might want to give a shot at MediaWiki (notably if the documentation is supposed to be written collaboratively). Intel is using a wiki on their intranet. [source](http://www.socialmedia.biz/2010/07/08/the-story-of-intelpedia-a-model-corporate-wiki/)

About Google Apps: not sure if it really fits the definition of an intRAnet. I wouldn't be comfortable with leaving my company's internal data on some stranger's cloud. But it could indeed be suitable if low budget is a priority over proper privacy.

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with either of them really closely, but I think you should also give a try to [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) and even better start with the [free](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) version.

Among other great features that the company can be benefitted from, you can create the intranet using [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com).